# c++ overriding default function in templated class

Tags: c++, function, templates

As a learning exercise, I wanted to make my own Hash Table class (yes, I know about std::unordered_map and std::unordered set). So, I wrote this code:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;

template <class K, class V, class U=std::hash<K>>
class hashTable
{
    int order=0;
    vector<myNode<K, V>> nodes;
public:
    hashTable(U u = U()){}; //  : hashPtr(u) 
    size_t gethash(K key, int level=0, const U & u=U());
};

template<class K, class V, class U>
size_t hashTable<K, V, U>::gethash(K key, int level, const U & u)
{
    return u(key) % divisors[level];
}
```

And it compiles fine and does what I expect when in main I have:

```
hashTable<int,int> hast;
for(int i=0;i<40;++i)
    cout << "hash of "<<i<<" is " << hast.gethash(i, 2) << endl;
```

However, when I write the following function:

```
size_t nodeHash(myNode<int,int> node) {
    int i = node.getkey();
    int j = node.getvalue();
    std::hash<int> hash_fn;
    return hash_fn(i)+hash_fn(j);
}
```

and in main I write:

```
hashTable < myNode<int, int>, int, nodeHash> hashMyNode;
```

I get the compilation error: function "nodeHash" is not a type name.

I know that I don't know what I am doing because these templated functions are new to me. I seem to know just enough to be "dangerous." However, if someone were able to nudge me in the right direction or give me a full-fledged solution to include an external function into a class (like std::unordered_map or std::sort does), I certainly would appreciate it.

Edit:

```
auto node = myNode<int, int>(1, 3);
hashTable < myNode<int, int>, int, size_t (*)(myNode<int,int> node)> hashMyNode;
hashMyNode.gethash(node, 2, nodeHash);
```

I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1776   function "myNode<K, V>::myNode(const myNode<int, int> &) [with K=int, V=int]" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function    somePrime   E:\source\repos\somePrime\somePrime.cpp 139
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'myNode<int,int>::myNode(const myNode<int,int> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  somePrime   e:\source\repos\someprime\someprime.cpp 139
```

this refers to the node variable.

Comment: `myNode`, `divisors` ?

Comment: `nodeHash` is not a type, but a function, you cannot use it as template parameter like that. `hashTable < myNode<int, int>, int, size_t (*)(myNode<int,int> node)>` and provide `nodeHash` after to `gethash` is a possibility. or create a functor.

Comment: divisors are a table of prime numbers that are near 2^n.  So, I added the following: 
      `hashTable < myNode<int, int>, int, size_t (*)(myNode<int,int> node)> hashMyNode;
      hashMyNode.gethash(node, 2, nodeHash);`
And I got a bundle of errors

Comment: I cannot figure out this comment editor within the 5 minute time limit.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42. I'm incompetent with these comments.

Comment: For your edit: `auto node = myNode<int, int>(1, 3);` should be `myNode<int, int> node(1, 3);` (prioir C++17), and `gethash` should take parameter by const reference instead of value to avoid (deleted) copy: `size_t gethash(const K& key, int level=0, const U & u=U());`. Or `myNode` should be copy constructible.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `std` namespace and specialize the `hash` template for your node type as:

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<myNode<int, int>>
{
    std::size_t operator()(myNode<int, int> const& node) const {
        int i = node.getkey();
        int j = node.getvalue();
        std::hash<int> hash_fn;
        return hash_fn(i)+hash_fn(j);
    }
};
}
```

and then create a table as:

```
hashTable < myNode<int, int>, int> hashMyNode;
```

now instead of using a function as a hash, you can create hash for your node as `std::hash<myNode<int,int>> hash_fn{}` but you don't have to explicitly create them, because you've already providing it type as default parameter (3rd parameter) of `hashTable`